# Nginx+Django error: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS or 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: django, nginx

I'm trying to deploy a django app with NGINX reverse-proxy server.

My `/etc/nginx/conf.f/app.conf` looks like this:

```
server {

  listen 80;
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name myhost.com;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/myhost.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/myhost.com/privkey.pem;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
}
```

When I open myhost.com, I get browser's `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` error. I don't know how to fix it, but if I rewrite `http://127.0.0.1:8000` as `https://127.0.0.1:8000`, I get `502 Bad Gateway` error.

Django is listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000.

Answer (score 0):

I think this has something to do with trailing slash in URL.

Try to change line

```
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
```

to

```
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
```

this might solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

In `settings.py`, set `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = False`.